# How can I generate a GRPC Java Stubs from python project?

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've just been following the GRPC [python tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html) and I've managed to implement a python server and client (that work fine). But what I really want is a python server and a java client. However, when I run `python -m grpc_tools.protoc --help` there is only a `--python_out` option and not a `--java_out`.

If I do something like this `protoc -I=. --java_out=. protos/*.proto` it won't generate the GRPC stubs that I need for the client.

---

Do I need to manually copy + paste the `.proto` file into a java project and use the gradle plugin to generate the stubs? That doesn't seem like the right way to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

For the java client, you need to use the stub generated by the java protobuf plugin, which need to be installed separately. Can you please take a look at this link:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler